# React JSX/Babel double quotes getting transformed to &quot;

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have a server rendered React App.

In my JSX a double quote `"` is getting transformed to `&quot;`

I am guessing it could be babel which is doing this? Any ideas? How do I retain the double quotes?

The double quote is part of a string.

Like this `<script> {' some text " '} </script>`

Notice the double quotes after `'some text'` above

I tried to use a `back tick (`)` instead of the single quote for the string, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I am able to successfully run and display the text.

please see this

https://codepen.io/sigar/pen/boGKyr?q=react&limit=all&type=type-pens

```
var SomeText = React.createClass({
```

render: function() {
    return (

```
  <div >
  {' some text " '}
  </div>
);
```

}
});

React.render(
  , 
  document.getElementById('app'));

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is some kind of babel transform which is causing the problem for me, as pure JSX seems to be fine from your example. Or could it be the codepen display which changes the &quot; back to a double quote?